# Forest tree with folders on every last relative level

Tags: forest

I want to create a tree, where the children at the last parent node of each branch are arranged as a folder. Based on some other posts I created the example shown below. However, my problem with this example is that the folders in the center (B.2.2.2, B.2.2.1, and B.2.1) have a weird large horizontal distance and thus the nodes overlap.

Is there some way to adjust this space or is there maybe even a more elegant way to create folders on each relative last level (with proper alignment)?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur,positioning,fit} 
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
        forked edges,
        basic/.style = {draw, thin, drop shadow, font=\sffamily},
        upper style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, edge+={-Stealth, thin}, fill=black!6, text width=10.5em},
          lower style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=0pt, edge+={-, line width=.4pt}, fill=black!10, text width=9em},
          where n children=0{%
            lower style
          }{%
            upper style,
          },
          where level<=1{%
            parent anchor=children,
            child anchor=parent,
            if={isodd(n_children())}{%
              calign=child edge,
              calign primary child/.process={
                O+nw+n{n children}{(#1+1)/2}
              },
            }{%
              calign=edge midpoint,
            },
          }{
            grow'=0,
          },
           [{Root},fill=parent,
            [{A}, folder, grow'=0, for children={lower style},
              before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }
                [A.1]
                [A.2]
                [...]
            ]
            [{B}, 
              [{B.1},   folder,   before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }
                [B.1.1]
                [B.1.2]
              ]
              [{B.2},  grow'=south,  parent anchor=children,
            child anchor=parent,
            if={isodd(n_children())}{%
              calign=child edge,
              calign primary child/.process={
                O+nw+n{n children}{(#1+1)/2}
              },
            }{%
              calign=edge midpoint,
            },
                [{B.2.1},  folder,   before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }
                    [B.2.1.2]
                    [B.2.1.3]
                    [B.2.1.4]
                    [B.2.1.5]
                    ]
              [{B.2.2}, grow'=south,parent anchor=children,
            child anchor=parent,calign=edge midpoint,
                [{B.2.2.1},  folder,   before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }
                    [B.2.2.1.1]
                    [B.2.2.1.2]
                    [B.2.2.1.3]
                ]
                [{B.2.2.2},  folder,   before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }
                    [B.2.2.2.1]
                    [B.2.2.2.2]
                    [B.2.2.2.3]
                ]
              ]]
              [{B.3},  folder,   before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }  
                [B.3.1]
                [B.3.2]
                [B.3.3]
              ]
            ]
            [{C}, folder, grow'=0,
              before drawing tree={
                tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
                tempdima-/.option=max y,
                for tree={
                  y+/.register=tempdima,
                },
              }
                [C.1]
                [C.2]
            ]
          ] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: change `grow'=south` (set on nodes `B.2` and `B.2.2`) to `grow=south` (without the apostrophe).

Prettified (and compilable) code (with some comments):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}

\forestset{
  calign to midchild or edge midpoint/.style={
    if={isodd(n_children())}{
      calign=child edge,
      calign primary child/.process={
        O+nw+n{n children}{(##1+1)/2}
      },
    }{
      calign=edge midpoint,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  basic/.style = {draw, thin, drop shadow, font=\sffamily},
  upper style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, edge+={-Stealth, thin}, fill=black!6, text width=10.5em},
  lower style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=0pt, edge+={-, line width=.4pt}, fill=black!10, text width=9em},
  my fork/.style={
    grow=south, calign to midchild or edge midpoint,
  },
  my folder/.style={
    % This does not work but it should. The following release of Forest will fix the issue by changing "s+=tempdims()*(reversed()-0.5)*2," to "s+=tempdims()*(reversed("!parent")-0.5)*2," in the definition of style "folder".
    % grow'=0,
    % The workaround is to set "grow'" for the entire subtree.
    for tree={grow'=0},
    folder,
    % This code lifts the entire folder a little bit, but.
    % (a) It could do so more elegantly, by changing "l" before computing xy,
    % instead of changing "y" after computing xy.
    % (b) It relies on some accidental properties of the tree. "!r2" is the
    % second child of the root, which is "anchor"ed at the base by default, so
    % "max y" is the non-zero. The folder nodes are "anchor"ed on top, so their
    % "max y" is zero.  "tempdima" thus results in some, rather arbitrary
    % shift.
    % 
    % before drawing tree={
    %   tempdima/.option=!r2.max y,
    %   tempdima-/.option=max y,
    %   for tree={
    %     y+/.register=tempdima,
    %   },
    % }
    % 
    % A better way to do this is to explicitly shift the folder nodes by
    % changing their "l" at the right time.  Note that while this will work for
    % this tree, it could result in overlapping nodes in general (but the same
    %   was true for the approach above).
    before computing xy={l-=2.5ex},
  },
  for tree={
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    if n children=0{
      lower style,
    }{
      upper style,
      % By default, we set "my fork" for all branching nodes.  We can do this
      % as everything it does is overriden by "my folder" (which is set
      %   manually for selected nodes).
      my fork,
    },
  },
  [Root,
    [A, my folder,
      [A.1]
      [A.2]
      [\dots]
    ]
    [B, 
      [B.1, my folder,
        [B.1.1]
        [B.1.2]
      ]
      [B.2,
        [B.2.1, my folder,
          [B.2.1.2]
          [B.2.1.3]
          [B.2.1.4]
          [B.2.1.5]
        ]
        [B.2.2,
          [B.2.2.1, my folder,
            [B.2.2.1.1]
            [B.2.2.1.2]
            [B.2.2.1.3]
          ]
          [B.2.2.2, my folder,
            [B.2.2.2.1]
            [B.2.2.2.2]
            [B.2.2.2.3]
          ]
        ]]
      [B.3, my folder,
        [B.3.1]
        [B.3.2]
        [B.3.3]
      ]
    ]
    [C, my folder, 
      [C.1]
      [C.2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: the result]

The long answer. The big question is how can using `grow` instead of `grow'` on the *parent* of the folder root influence how the folder looks like?!

First, unlike `grow`, `grow'` sets `reversed` to true (note that in OPs picture, `B.2.1` and `B.2.2`are reversed, and so are `B.2.2.1` and `B.2.2.2`).

Style `folder` sets the `anchor` of the parent node (i.e. the folder root) to `parent first`. This is crucial, because the style then shifts the children with this reference point in mind to produce the visual effect of a folder. However, the `parent first` anchor depends on the `reversed` (and `grow`) of the parent of the node it is used at --- in this case, the parent of the folder. (I will have to think about whether this is a (design) bug or not.) So what was really happening here was that the parent node (and not the children) got thrown to a wrong place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and the provided explanations! Also, thank you for the development of the forest package.